# Get the size of multi dimensional std::array at compile time via constexpr or template function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-meta-programming, constexpr

I use a three dimensional `std::array`, because the size is already known at compile. However, I noticed that the size() function is not static, and thus, inaccessible for constexpr/template functions.

I already found the demo example below, which estimates the size of a one dimensional `std::array`. However, this does not work for two or more dimensions. Is there a way to return the other dimensions by writing a function with an additional template parameter `dim` for the `x, y, z, ..` dimension?

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

// typedefs for certain container classes
template<class T, size_t x>
using array1D = std::array<T, x>;
template<class T, size_t x, size_t y>
using array2D = std::array<std::array<T, y>, x>;
template<class T, size_t x, size_t y, size_t z>
using array3D = std::array<std::array<std::array<T, z>, y>, x>;


template<class T, std::size_t N>
auto array_size_helper(const array1D<T, N>&) -> std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N>;

template<class Array>
using array_size = decltype(array_size_helper(std::declval<const Array&>()));

template<class Array>
constexpr auto static_size() -> decltype(array_size<Array>::value) {
  return array_size<Array>::value;
}
template<class Array>
constexpr auto static_size(Array const&) -> decltype(static_size<Array>()) {
  return static_size<Array>();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << static_size<array3D<float, 3, 4, 5>>();
}
```

Comment: In your example with `array3D<float, 3, 4, 5>` what would the size be? `3`? `4`? `5`? Or `3 * 4 * 5`?

Comment: You're providing constant sizes. Why can't you just multiply their individual sizes and get the total size?

Comment: In my example I just get the X dimension: 3. The other two are not included :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the one dimensional case, you could use `std::tuple_size` which is defined for `std::array` as well:

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::tuple_size<array3D<float, 3, 4, 5>>();
}
```

Regarding your actual problem. If I understand you right you want to have an additional parameter on your size function with which you can select the dimension for which the size should be returned, right?

This can be done easily by using recursion. Here is a working example:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

// typedefs for certain container classes
template<class T, size_t x>
using array1D = std::array<T, x>;

template<class T, size_t x, size_t y>
using array2D = std::array<std::array<T, y>, x>;

template<class T, size_t x, size_t y, size_t z>
using array3D = std::array<std::array<std::array<T, z>, y>, x>;


template <size_t dim, typename Array>
struct size_of_dim;

// specialization for std array and first dimension
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct size_of_dim<0, std::array<T,N>> : std::integral_constant<size_t, N> {};

// specialization for std array and dimension > 0 → recurse down in dim
template <size_t dim, typename InnerArray, size_t N>
struct size_of_dim<dim, std::array<InnerArray,N>> : size_of_dim<dim-1,InnerArray> {};



int main()
{
    std::cout << size_of_dim<0,array3D<float, 3, 4, 5>>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << size_of_dim<1,array3D<float, 3, 4, 5>>() << std::endl;
    std::cout << size_of_dim<2,array3D<float, 3, 4, 5>>() << std::endl;
}
```

[DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0z8g3ccE8ac6uwOw)

Comment: This is a very nice solution.